# Stop pandas/numpy from saving a type of data as a number?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-wrangling

I am trying to create a program that reads in multiple sheets of an excel regarding 96 well plates (like cell culture plates) and assigns them to a dataframe. It is trying to organize the dataframe so for each sheet it will read it in, receive a title from the top left cell of the plate, and then add it to a dataframe such that:

| Well | data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 6B4 | 0.145 |
| A2 | 6E5 | 0.132 |
| A3 | 6C9 | 0.015 |

But as you can see above, well A2 poses a problem as pandas wants to read the value in as 6000000000.0 instead of "6E5"

I have tried formatting the columns in the excel as text, but to no effect. I have also tried identifying when the title is "barcode" and forcing it to load as a string but I think the problem originates from .read_excel() so the value is already stored as 6000000000.0

Opened the question again as I have assured multiple times it is not an excel problem and one of the links posted in response says that it is a problem with non-excel generated data that has been exported to excel (which this is not). I have tried saving the sheet as a csv and it has no problem saving the values as text.

Comment: I fairly sure that the number is already converted from `6E5` to `600000` **in excel** and that your issue has nothing to do with pandas/`read_excel`. Please double check.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I have checked the excel cells and they are formatted as numbers - I am on a mac, would this affect anything?

Comment: I don't think the OS changes anything, just force the format as string within excel.

Comment: Side note: in Excel, formatting and the underlying value are not equivalent. You can apply number format to text, and vice versa. HIghly suggest you prepend the value with `'`, so `'6E5`.

Comment: I added some links to potentially relevant QAs, in the end the question is most likely about Excel and thus offtopic on SO

Comment: hey  BigBen, I prepended all the values to no effect - they cells are formatted as text and all have '  in front of them. I'm really struggling to understand how it is an excel problem if as far as it knows those values are text.

Comment: please see edit, saving the sheet as a csv poses no problems with the text values.